# /sbin/route survive reboot

Tags: linux, networking

I run this command to get the the internet working on a server of mine. 174.0.0.1 represents the gateway for the VLAN. What do I have to do to make this change survive a reboot?

```
/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 174.0.0.1 eth0
```

Comment: What distro are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your distribution.

If it's a Debian-derivative or Red Hat-derivative, edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add a `gateway` entry to the active network interface.

On next reboot, it will be set.

Comment: If it's a Red Hat derivative, edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$INTERFACE and set GATEWAY=174.0.0.1.

Comment: @200_success, heh-- sorry for not posting the distro, you nailed it